# SSIS: Package Sequence and Performance

Tags: ssis

I have a main SSIS package that runs all my other packages.  Even though some packages are not dependent on each other, is it always better for performance to put them in a sequence or is it better to run them at the same time (no sequence)?

Comment: The answer to this is heavily dependent on what the packages do.  If they all hit the same DB/fileshare while the DB/fileshare is under load, then sequential is likely better.  If not, then run them in parallel.  The only real way to know is to benchmark both approaches in your environment.

Comment: They are all going into the same DB in SQL-Server extension DBs for MS Dynamics CRM.  It sounds like the latter of your approach would perform better for me.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/parallel-execution-in-ssis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric has mentioned it truly depends on what the packages do, but I would say if the packages are related to different tables, from my limited experience I have seen better results with having packages run in parallel. I would advice you to go by the dependencies and arrange packages in sequence containers based on which ones can be run parallel. The SSIS engine does a pretty good job of running parallel tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input.